# Network congestion calculate real time

Tags: ether

Is there a formula that I can use to calculate current network congestion of Ethereum network or any other crypto currency ?
I tried to search for it but couldn't find anything on it.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

"Congestion" is a relative term.

Firstly, a user who submits a transaction with a lower gas price will experience more "congestion" than a user whose transaction has a higher gas price.

Secondly, what is considered congestion, rather than normal network latency, is subjective, and will be different for different users who have managed their expectations differently.

> Is there a formula that I can use to calculate current network congestion

I don't know how to calculate this (someone else might). I think it will depend on the whole of the gas market: how many transactions are pending and at what gas price, how full the blocks are (and how full the miners are filling them), and so on.

EthGasStation's [Predicted Confirm Times By Gas Price For Transactions](https://ethgasstation.info/predictionTable.php) presumably uses a formula similar to the one you're looking for, so it might just be easier to screen-scrape from their page.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's a function that takes into consideration the time required to execute a transaction with double the median gas price of the latest n blocks